# coupling jquery datatable and kendo data source

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui

I have a dataSource table using Kendo. I need to do the filtering like in jquery.dataTable.
Is there a way to do get this by doing the coupling .
Or this is not possible.
this is may code for kendo datasource:

this is the javascript function to put json data in datasource table:

```
function koCreateTableACT(apidata) {

    function ACTModel(data) {
        if (!data) {
            data = {};
        }
        var item = data;
        var self = this;

        var self = this;
        self.Id= item.Id,
        self.Title= item.Title,
        self.IPS_START = new Date(item.IPS_START),
       self.IPS_END = new Date(item.IPS_END),


    }
    function ACTPageModel(data) {
        if (!data) {
            data = {};
        }

        var self = this;
        self.ACT = ExtractModels(self, data.ACT, ACTModel);

        var filters = [
            {
            },
            {
            }
        ];
        var sortOptions = [

        ];
        //MI CODE 05-11-2014

        //MI CODE 05-11-2014
        self.filter = new FilterModel(filters, self.ACT);
        self.sorter = new SorterModel(sortOptions, self.filter.filteredRecords);
        self.pager = new ACTPagerModel(self.sorter.orderedRecords);

        ////////

    }
    function ACTPagerModel(records) {
        var self = this;
        self.pageSizeOptions = ko.observableArray([1, 5, 25, 50, 100, 250, 500]);

        self.records = GetObservableArray(records);
        self.currentPageIndex = ko.observable(self.records().length > 0 ? 0 : -1);
        self.currentPageSize = ko.observable(25);
        self.recordCount = ko.computed(function () {
            return self.records().length;
        });
        self.maxPageIndex = ko.computed(function () {
            return Math.ceil(self.records().length / self.currentPageSize()) - 1;
        });
        self.currentPageRecordsACT = ko.computed(function () {
            var newPageIndex = -1;
            var pageIndex = self.currentPageIndex();
            var maxPageIndex = self.maxPageIndex();
            if (pageIndex > maxPageIndex) {
                newPageIndex = maxPageIndex;
            }
            else if (pageIndex == -1) {
                if (maxPageIndex > -1) {
                    newPageIndex = 0;
                }
                else {
                    newPageIndex = -2;
                }
            }
            else {
                newPageIndex = pageIndex;
            }

            if (newPageIndex != pageIndex) {
                if (newPageIndex >= -1) {
                    self.currentPageIndex(newPageIndex);
                }

                return [];
            }

            var pageSize = self.currentPageSize();
            var startIndex = pageIndex * pageSize;
            var endIndex = startIndex + pageSize;
            return self.records().slice(startIndex, endIndex);
        }).extend({ throttle: 5 });
        self.moveFirst = function () {
            self.changePageIndex(0);
        };
        self.movePrevious = function () {
            self.changePageIndex(self.currentPageIndex() - 1);
        };
        self.moveNext = function () {
            self.changePageIndex(self.currentPageIndex() + 1);
        };
        self.moveLast = function () {
            self.changePageIndex(self.maxPageIndex());
        };
        self.changePageIndex = function (newIndex) {
            if (newIndex < 0
                || newIndex == self.currentPageIndex()
                || newIndex > self.maxPageIndex()) {
                return;
            }

            self.currentPageIndex(newIndex);
        };
        self.onPageSizeChange = function () {
            self.currentPageIndex(0);
        };
        self.renderPagers = function () {
            var pager = "<div><a href=\"#\" data-bind=\"click: pager.moveFirst, enable: pager.currentPageIndex() > 0\">&lt;&lt;</a><a href=\"#\" data-bind=\"click: pager.movePrevious, enable: pager.currentPageIndex() > 0\">&lt;</a>Page <span data-bind=\"text: pager.currentPageIndex() + 1\"></span> of <span data-bind=\"text: pager.maxPageIndex() + 1\"></span> [<span data-bind=\"text: pager.recordCount\"></span> Record(s)]<select data-bind=\"options: pager.pageSizeOptions, value: pager.currentPageSize, event: { change: pager.onPageSizeChange }\"></select><a href=\"#\" data-bind=\"click: pager.moveNext, enable: pager.currentPageIndex() < pager.maxPageIndex()\">&gt;</a><a href=\"#\" data-bind=\"click: pager.moveLast, enable: pager.currentPageIndex() < pager.maxPageIndex()\">&gt;&gt;</a></div>";
            $("div.Pager").html(pager);
        };
        self.renderNoRecords = function () {
            var message = "<span data-bind=\"visible: pager.recordCount() == 0\">No records found.</span>";
            $("div.NoRecords").html(message);
        };
        self.addRecords = function () {


            //add methode ajout

        }

        self.addToGridView = function (data) {
            var item = data.d;
            self.records().push(new ACTModel({
                Id: item.Id,
                Title: item.Title,
                IPS_START: new Date(item.IPS_START),
                IPS_END: new Date(item.IPS_END),

            }));

            self.records.notifySubscribers();



        };

        self.removeACT = function (item) {
            alert(item);
            ko.utils.arrayRemoveItem(self.records(), item);
            self.records.notifySubscribers();
            /////

            DeleteItem(item.Id);
        };
        self.DisplayACT = function (item) {
            //add edit pop UP
            // Avgrund.show("#edit-popup");

        };
        self.renderPagers();
        self.renderNoRecords();

        //added by Imen
        self.tableVisible = ko.observable(true);

        self.edit = function (item) {


        };

    }
    function SorterModel(sortOptions, records) {
        var self = this;
        self.records = GetObservableArray(records);
        self.sortOptions = ko.observableArray(sortOptions);
        self.sortDirections = ko.observableArray([
            {
                Name: "Asc",
                Value: "Asc",
                Sort: false
            },
            {
                Name: "Desc",
                Value: "Desc",
                Sort: true
            }]);
        self.currentSortOption = ko.observable(self.sortOptions()[0]);
        self.currentSortDirection = ko.observable(self.sortDirections()[0]);
        self.orderedRecords = ko.computed(function () {
            var records = self.records();
            var sortOption = self.currentSortOption();
            var sortDirection = self.currentSortDirection();
            if (sortOption == null || sortDirection == null) {
                return records;
            }

            var sortedRecords = records.slice(0, records.length);
            SortArray(sortedRecords, sortDirection.Sort, sortOption.Sort);
            return sortedRecords;
        }).extend({ throttle: 5 });
    }
    function FilterModel(filters, records) {
        var self = this;
        self.records = GetObservableArray(records);
        self.filters = ko.observableArray(filters);
        self.activeFilters = ko.computed(function () {
            var filters = self.filters();
            var activeFilters = [];
            for (var index = 0; index < filters.length; index++) {
                var filter = filters[index];
                if (filter.CurrentOption) {
                    var filterOption = filter.CurrentOption();
                    if (filterOption && filterOption.FilterValue != null) {
                        var activeFilter = {
                            Filter: filter,
                            IsFiltered: function (filter, record) {
                                var filterOption = filter.CurrentOption();
                                if (!filterOption) {
                                    return;
                                }

                                var recordValue = filter.RecordValue(record);
                                return recordValue != filterOption.FilterValue; NoMat
                            }
                        };
                        activeFilters.push(activeFilter);
                    }
                }
                else if (filter.Value) {
                    var filterValue = filter.Value();
                    if (filterValue && filterValue != "") {
                        var activeFilter = {
                            Filter: filter,
                            IsFiltered: function (filter, record) {
                                var filterValue = filter.Value();
                                filterValue = filterValue.toUpperCase();

                                var recordValue = filter.RecordValue(record);
                                recordValue = recordValue.toUpperCase();
                                return recordValue.indexOf(filterValue) == -1;
                            }
                        };
                        activeFilters.push(activeFilter);
                    }
                }
            }

            return activeFilters;
        });
        self.filteredRecords = ko.computed(function () {
            var records = self.records();
            var filters = self.activeFilters();
            if (filters.length == 0) {
                return records;
            }

            var filteredRecords = [];
            for (var rIndex = 0; rIndex < records.length; rIndex++) {
                var isIncluded = true;
                var record = records[rIndex];
                for (var fIndex = 0; fIndex < filters.length; fIndex++) {
                    var filter = filters[fIndex];
                    var isFiltered = filter.IsFiltered(filter.Filter, record);
                    if (isFiltered) {
                        isIncluded = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (isIncluded) {
                    filteredRecords.push(record);
                }
            }

            return filteredRecords;
        }).extend({ throttle: 200 });
    }
    function ExtractModels(parent, data, constructor) {
        var models = [];
        if (data == null) {
            return models;
        }

        for (var index = 0; index < data.length; index++) {
            var row = data[index];
            var model = new constructor(row, parent);
            models.push(model);
        }

        return models;
    }
    function GetObservableArray(array) {
        if (typeof (array) == 'function') {
            return array;
        }

        return ko.observableArray(array);
    }
    function CompareCaseInsensitive(left, right) {
        if (left == null) {
            return right == null;
        }
        else if (right == null) {
            return false;
        }

        return left.toUpperCase() <= right.toUpperCase();
    }
    function GetOption(name, value, filterValue) {
        var option = {
            Name: name,
            Value: value,
            FilterValue: filterValue
        };
        return option;
    }
    function SortArray(array, direction, comparison) {
        if (array == null) {
            return [];
        }

        for (var oIndex = 0; oIndex < array.length; oIndex++) {
            var oItem = array[oIndex];
            for (var iIndex = oIndex + 1; iIndex < array.length; iIndex++) {
                var iItem = array[iIndex];
                var isOrdered = comparison(oItem, iItem);
                if (isOrdered == direction) {
                    array[iIndex] = oItem;
                    array[oIndex] = iItem;
                    oItem = iItem;
                }
            }
        }

        return array;
    }

    // Map data from SPListItem
    var jsonStr = JSON.stringify(apidata.d.results);
    var jsonPars = JSON.parse(jsonStr);

    var rever = jsonPars.reverse();
    var SPListItemP = $.map(rever, function (item) {
        return {
            //Populate data to load as table item (medecin, pharmacie et grossiste)

            Id: item.Id,
            Title: item.Title,
            IPS_START: new Date(item.IPS_START),
            IPS_END: new Date(item.IPS_END),

        };
    })

    // Create KO Table with filter
    var ACTItems = {
        ACT: SPListItemP
    };
    MYMODELACT = new ACTPageModel(ACTItems);
    ko.applyBindings(MYMODELACT);
}


<table id="datatable_example" class="responsive table table-striped table-bordered" style="width: 100%; margin-bottom: 0;">
                <thead>
                    <tr>

                        <th>Obj.Visite</th>

                        <th>Date Debut</th>

                        <th>Date Fin</th>



                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody data-bind="foreach: pager.currentPageRecordsACT">
                    <tr>

                        <td >
                            <span data-bind="text: Title"></span>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <span data-bind="text: start"></span>

                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <span data-bind="text: end"></span>
                        </td>

                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

and this is the jquery code :

```
$('#datatable_example').dataTable({

        });
```

when i do this i get the filter icon , the research input text , but they dont work .

Comment: Can you provide some code that you are trying?

Comment: Are you using kendoDataSource? Please provide the same

Comment: Yes i using kendoDataSource

Comment: Please provide sample fiddle for the datasource